# Odoo Loading Javascript

Tags: javascript, frameworks, odoo

I don't really understand how to load Javascript in Odoo. On Odoo official website, it mentions:

web.assets_backend: this bundle contains the code specific to the web client (notably the web client/action manager/views)

web.assets_frontend: this bundle is about all that is specific to the public website: ecommerce, portal, forum, blog, …

The part I don't understand is what defines a thing is 'web client' or 'public website'. Is there a sign to identify this?

The way I loaded my JS file until now is to try 1 way or another, either 'assets_backend' or 'assets_frontend'.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the customization you are doing. That is if you want to do customizations on the web portal, website, or eCommerce then it is considered as Front-End in Odoo hence add JS to `assets_frontend`.
If your customizations are on the Odoo interface i.e. after logging into the Odoo system which is ERP-centric then it is considered a Back-End hence add JS to `assets_backend`.
Also if you want to make any customizations in Point of Sale screens, you need to add JS files to `point_of_sale.assets`.